# npx <package> runs on command line but not in package.json scripts section

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a package installed in node using
`npm i mypackage --save-dev`
and it works fine on the command line with
`npx mypackage --options`
but when I want to have it in the package.json files scripts section it it fails. I tried

```
"scripts": {
 "mystuff": "mypackage --options",
 "mystuffnpm": "npm run mypackage --options",
 "mystuffnpx": "npx mypackage --options"
}
```

but nothing works. What is the right way to get it in the scripts section running?

Comment: How are you executing the `scripts`? Are you using `npm run mystuffnpx`? Also are you trying to pass any additional command line arguements as options with your `script` command?

Comment: Can you post the error/s please?

Comment: the actual case is `npx m2j -cp ./src/news/*.md -o ./src/news/news.json` which works fine on the command line

Comment: I'm trying `"news": "./node_modules/.bin/m2j -c ./src/news/*.md -o ./src/news/news.json"` in the scripts section. Then the error is `ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat './src/news/*.md'`

Answer (score 0):

1. After integrating any package without command try "npx run".It will
   install the missing packages in node modules.
2. Make sure you are running the command in the specific directory.
3. Try "npm init -y" to make new package.json file and then install the
   packages.

Comment: cd to `node_modules/.bin` and do `./m2j ../../src/news/*.md` works well. Using this full relative path in the script section leads to `ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '../../src/news/*.md'` So, apparently, the package is known but the file path is the problem an different to the command line.